# Traffic b/w business logic layer and database incoming/outgoing chargeable?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-traffic-manager

In Azure traffic b/w business logic layer and database incoming/outgoing is chargeable?

If yes, how to calculate the cost?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the Bandwidth Pricing details [**here**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/bandwidth/)

Irrespective of the services you consume, data transfer is billed specifically for outbound transfer. you will be metered for all data leaving a given region.

You can [calculate](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) the charge by creating a POC as it might differ since it involves lot of other details/payload.